# Very hot live pin on kettle plug

Tags: power-dissipation, fault

I moved my kettle just after boiling it yesterday and noticed the live pin was very hot. None of the other pins are hot. It's a bs 1363 type plug and socket. And a <2 year old kettle.

After a full kettle its burning hot!

It's the same even from different sockets.

Is this normal for a 2kW appliance?
Is it indicating a fuse at the end of life, or bad socket wiring, bad plug wiring?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mention the type of plug but your user profile says UK so it's a 13 A plug.

[image]

*Figure 1. Photo by Pfnicholls at [WikiMedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:UK_13A_Plug_top_view.JPG).*

The L pin runs warmer than the others due to the heat generated by the (low) resistance of the built-in fuse and, possibly, the fuse contacts.

If you're concerned then replace the kettle lead or, if you know what you're doing, you can cut the plug off and use a rewireable type.

---

According to [The Art of Sound](https://theartofsound.net/forum/showthread.php?25272-Does-anyone-know-the-impedance-of-a-13A-fuse#:%7E:text=%5B2%5D%20The%20DC%20resistance%20of,of%2013A%20rating%20is%204mOhm.) forum the 13 A fuse resistance is in the order of 10 mΩ.

- Your 2 kW kettle will draw \$ I = \frac P V = \frac {2000}{230} = 8.7 \ \text A \$.
- The heat dissipated in the fuse will be given by \$ P = I^2R = 8.7^2 \times 10m = 0.75 \ \text W \$. In normal practice this should be conducted away by the terminals and wiring. The fact that it is not suggest that a lot more power is being dissipated and this is most likely due to poor contact somewhere.

You could try removing the fuse and pinching the contacts together before reinserting the fuse. The extra "bite" may lower the contact resistance.

Comment: Thanks, amended the original answer for the plug type. I couldn't actually find any info about expected resistance of the contacts, despite looking quite hard. Sounds like it's the fuse then since none of the other pins are hot. Fortunately it's already a rewireable type!

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I double checked the kettle power, it's actually 3kW but that will only increase power dissipation to about 1.7W. Plug is actually a pain to open, even once the screws are off, so I'll update when I've figured out how to get the cap off

Answer (score 0):

It could be just bad contact, but it can be also that the heater is broken and that current is now flowing through protective earth, if your installation has a GFCI it should also trigger it. According to your description it will soon start to burn, so you'd better dispose it.